# Cannot implicitly convert type 'Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.IHost' to 'Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.IHostBuilder'

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

I have an application that's going to be running with both HTTP and HTTPS on AWS (redirecting to HTTPS where possible), and I keep getting the error above when I try to build it. Here's the code for mine:

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
namespace gradesApp {
    public class Program {
        public static void Main(string[] args) {
            CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }

        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder => {
                    webBuilder
                    .UseKestrel(options => {
                                    options.Listen(IPAddress.Loopback, 5000);                    // http:localhost:5000
                                    options.Listen(IPAddress.Loopback, 5001, listenOptions => {  // https:localhost:5001
                                        listenOptions.UseHttps("certificate.pfx");
                                    });
                                    options.Listen(IPAddress.Any, 80);                           // http:*:80
                                    options.Listen(IPAddress.Any, 443, listenOptions => {        // https:*:443
                                        listenOptions.UseHttps("certificate.pfx");
                                    });
                                })
                    .UseStartup<Startup>();
                })
                .Build();
    }
}
```

Is there something I'm missing here?
By request, here is the error itself:

```
/source/aspnetapp/Program.cs(18,13): error CS0266: Cannot implicitly convert type 'Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.IHost' to 'Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.IHostBuilder'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?) [/source/aspnetapp/gradesApp.csproj]
```

Comment: Which line do you get the error on?

Comment: I get the error on line 18, in other words, `Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)`

Comment: @ColtonRushton: Include the error description to your post.

Comment: @Jackdaw Error description is in post now

Answer (score 1):

Remove `.Build()` after `.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)`.

As `CreateHostBuilder` expects for value with `IHostBuilder` type.

With `.Build()` it returns `IHost` which is unmatched type with `IHostBuilder`.

```cs
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
    Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder => {
            webBuilder
            .UseKestrel(options => {
                ...
            })
            .UseStartup<Startup>();
        });
```

Comment: That worked, but now I have a different error on startup: `Unhandled exception. Interop+Crypto+OpenSslCryptographicException: error:2006D080:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:no such file`

Comment: Hi, I think this [Github issue](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/36333)may helps you.